# ASM code in KMDF driver

Tags: c++, assembly, kmdf

I added asm source to KMDF driver project:

```
.CODE

read_port PROC port : WORD, result_ptr : PTR BYTE

    mov dx, port
    in al, dx                       ; read port

    mov rbx, result_ptr
    mov BYTE PTR [rbx], al          ; place value at result address

ret

read_port ENDP

END
```

In Driver.c file I can call read_port like this:

```
extern void read_port(unsigned short port, unsigned char* result);

//...

unsigned char val;
read_port(0, &val);
```

However I can't call this function like that from additional source file, for example test.cpp. Complier gives me unresolved external.

test.cpp:

```
extern void read_port(unsigned short port, unsigned char* result);

//...

unsigned char val;
read_port(0, &val);         // unresolved external
```

What is the reason?

Comment: How about if you use `extern "C"` in the .cpp file?

Comment: Also, make sure the calling conventions match. On x86-64 arguments are typically passed in registers, no idea about KMDF.

Comment: Maybe add a `public` for read_port?

Comment: You can use `READ_PORT_UCHAR` instead of fiddling with assembly.